# Mongo Shard Replica Cluster - status

Tags: mongodb

i have setup two Replica Sets rs1 (2 nodes + 1 arbiter), rs2 (2 nodes + 1 arbiter)
and 3 config servers and 1 router.

enabled sharding on a database, and sharded a collection.

actually on the shard status it only shows one chunk used on one rs1

```
use demo;
db.printShardingStatus()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5656c10e6e54e468ee4e07f6")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "rs1",  "host" : "rs1/192.168.99.103:27018,192.168.99.104:27018" }
    {  "_id" : "rs2",  "host" : "rs2/192.168.99.103:27019,192.168.99.104:27019" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "demo",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rs1" }
        demo.uploads
            shard key: { "missionId" : "hashed" }
            chunks:
                rs1 1
            { "missionId" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "missionId" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs1 Timestamp(1, 0) 
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "rs2" }
```

how can i verify that my `rs2`is going  to get used on growing of the `uploads` collection?

edit: there are only a few dummy documents inside the uploads collection.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `uploads` collection is hash sharded on `missionId` key, you can simply verify balancing on rs2 by pumping some documents to `uploads` collection. Choose monotonically increasing number for `missonId` when you do so

Comment: thx did a for loop and bumped in some documents and it immediatly starting to use all `rs`